# Move a group by panning

Tags: libgdx

I want to move a group of Actors by panning.

```
 @Override
public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    Gdx.app.debug(TAG," Delta " + deltaX * screen.ppu + " old x "+ screen.getLevelGroup().getX());

    float newX = screen.getLevelGroup().getX() + deltaX * screen.ppu;
    Gdx.app.debug(TAG,"new X " + newX);
    screen.getLevelGroup().setX(newX);


    return true;
}
```

Sometimes this doesn't work. It seems  the X property of group is changed between getting and setting. Please note that it is not happening all of the time.
The bugous log file is as follow:

> StageSelectorGestureDetector:  Delta 7.5117373 old x -639.64
> StageSelectorGestureDetector: new X -632.1283
>
> StageSelectorGestureDetector:  Delta 7.5117373 old x -639.566
>
> StageSelectorGestureDetector: new X -632.05426
>
> StageSelectorGestureDetector:  Delta 9.765259 old x -639.5344
>
> StageSelectorGestureDetector: new X -629.76917
>
> StageSelectorGestureDetector:  Delta 5.258216 old x -639.5344

Notice that even though I am setting the X, reading it on the next invocation of pan reports the old value.

Can some one help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that an Action was still active when panning, so two method was competing to set the coordination of the group, hence the strange behaviour.